# Vb.net application to run on desktop + windows mobile 6 - Which database to use?

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, sql-server-ce, windows-mobile-6

i would like to build an inventory manager application that would have two versions :
1. Would run on the desktop 
2. Would run on windows mobile 6

I would like to have both these versions store and read data from a database that can be stored centrally either on a webserver or somewhere on the LAN.

I would like to know can i use Access as my backend database or sql server ? will windows mobile app be able to access it and read and write to it ?

Note : I would prefer to create only one database that will just store the details in the tables and do not need any other functionality. All functions such as save,edit,delete,search,filter etc with be done from the FRONT-END VB.NET interface ONLY

If you suggestion involves the use of 2 databases such as one for desktop version and one for windows mobile then please also tell me how would i sync the data between them.

Thanks!

Comment: To the best of my knowledge you can't run an access database on win mobile 6. There was Sql Compact for that. But your question is not clear, if the database is stored centrally what do you want to store on the windows mobile?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't want to store anything on the windows mobile. I just want to build two front-end UI's one will be for windows mobile and one will be for desktop. Both of them will read and write data from a database that i want to stored somewhere centrally wherein both can access it and modify the data and do specific functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I both your devices are always connected, you can use SQL Server with both.

Comment: Thanks Erik. Can you point me to some tutorial on links how i would go about doing this. Do i have to build some kind of webservice or what exactly do i need to know and will there b any issues in updating the database. At the most 5 users will be using the app at the same time. Also, Both the devices will be connected at all times. The windows mobile 6 will be connected thru the wifi. Thanks!

Comment: You can use System.data.sqlclient and simply create a ADO.NET SqlConnection from both devices...

Comment: > You can use System.data.sqlclient and simply create a ADO.NET SqlConnection from both devices... No, you can't. This is not possible with Windows Mobile devices. But I am also searching for a solution.

Comment: Oh yes, you can: http://sampath.wordpress.com/2007/03/20/connecting-to-sql-server-express-from-a-pocket-pc-application/